# C : string concatenation of multiple string truncates the portion of string after concatenation

Tags: c, string, string-concatenation

I have to concatenate multiple strings as a single string in c and for the same using the snprintf,

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char id[] =  "D0D0-0000-0000-0000-0001-A431";
  char mac[] = "fc017c0f2b75";
  char aid[] = "1";

  printf("size of id :: %ld\n", sizeof(id));
  printf("size of mac :: %ld\n", sizeof(mac));
  printf("size of aid :: %ld\n", sizeof(aid));

  char *uniqueID = (char*)malloc(50);
  snprintf(uniqueID, sizeof(uniqueID), "%s.%s.%s", id, mac, aid);
  printf("uniqueID :: %s\n", uniqueID);
  printf("size of uniqueID :: %ld\n", sizeof(uniqueID));
}
```

and for the given requirements using the above code, i can able to produce the below result,

```
size of id :: 30
size of mac :: 13
size of aid :: 2
uniqueID :: D0D0-00
size of uniqueID :: 8
```

whereas, the required result is,

```
size of uniqueID :: D0D0-0000-0000-0000-0001-A431.fc017c0f2b75.1
```

What is an issue here? How to resolve this?

Comment: `sizeof(uniqueID)` this is not what you want. `uniqueID` is a pointer, not an array. Therefore you only get size 8.

Comment: Not causing the problem but type of `sizeof` is `size_t` which can be printed using `%zu` format specifier. Don't use `%ld` unless you are using an ancient pre C99 compiler.

Comment: @Gerhardh, in case he want to compile that in a pre C99 compiler (in addition to do it in a post C99 one) he can use `"%lu"`, but casting the `size_t` argument to `(unsigned long)` in the `printf()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size you provided for `snprintf` is incorrect (`sizeof(uniqueID)` is the size of the pointer = `8`). For your case, it should've been:

```
  snprintf(uniqueID, 50, "%s.%s.%s", id, mac, aid);
```

Had uniqueID been an array as shown below, your program would've worked alright (`sizeof(uniqueID)` is the size of the char array = `50`) :

```
  char uniqueID[50] = {};
  snprintf(uniqueID, sizeof(uniqueID), "%s.%s.%s", id, mac, aid);
```